# libGDX TrueTypeFont font working with accented characters on windows

Tags: windows, libgdx, cross-platform, non-ascii-characters

So we made a small hangman game, and because we are Hungarians we have those irritating accented characters. libGDX can perfectly draw these on Android and Linux, but it just skips them on Windows. I have included 3 screenshots from the 3 systems. The font is self-made ttf font, I have also included, it only has the required letters.

When generating the font I included the characters like so:

```
parameter.characters = "aábcdeéfghiíjklmnoóöőpqrstuúüűvwxyz_"
```

[Font (Mega link)](https://mega.nz/#!1Y0RTZbK!gnt88d1P4PLZx9V2paTPnrmV-Qv_9IO_XP-4Fn3OKfs)

- Windows: Supposed to say sütőlap(oventop)
  [image: Windows]
- Linux: pöröly(sledge hammer)
  [image: Linux]
- Android: színész(actor)
  [image: Android]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using the Apache commons-IO library and specifying utf-8 encoding for reading the file, as it turned out that was the problem.